# Twilio Error: "12200 Schema validation warning Description Invalid content was found starting with element 'Message'. One of '{Play"

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-php

I am getting this error from Twilio.

> 12200 Schema validation warning Description  Invalid content was found
>   starting with element 'Message'. One of '{Play

The markup is formed like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Response>
   <Message to="+999999999" from="+9999999">Thank you for request</Message>
   <Redirect>http://www.x.com/twiml/applet/voice/1/1df17f</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This looks like it would be absolutely fine in response to an incoming SMS message. However, as your `<Redirect>` url suggests, this is a voice application. So, my guess is that you are trying to send an SMS message during the course of a call.

You can do that, but not using the `<Message>` verb. You need to use the [`<Sms>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms) verb instead. The good news is, that's all you'd need to change. So your response would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Sms to="+999999999" from="+9999999">Thank you for request</Sms>
  <Redirect>http://www.x.com/twiml/applet/voice/1/1df17f</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Let me know if I've got this right or if my diagnosis was way off and I'll try to help again!

Comment: Thanks, but this error message should really be made clearer!

Comment: Also, it seems this uses the deprecated /SMS/Messages resource. What would be the way to do it now?

Comment: This doesn't use `/SMS/Messages` as that is a resource in the REST API. If you want to send an SMS message as part of a voice call you should use the [`<Sms>` element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms).

Comment: I see. But then why doesn't it provide delivery steps info? Does this depend on the country of the sending number?

Comment: What do you mean "delivery steps info"? The error message is correct in that it is not valid in TwiML to place a `<Message>` element inside a voice response. The TwiML that you use does not depend on the country of a sending number either, and notably this is not the case of a number being sent to, but sending a message as part of a voice call.

Comment: The message is technically correct but come on it's weirdly formatted and looks truncated. For the "delivery steps": when I send an SMS using <sms> then look in the log under twilio.com/console/sms/logs/, I see: "Delivery Steps are not available" then a message about /SMS/Messages deprecation. Also the size is limited to 160 characters. Why am I not getting the upgrades described here? https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181028-Switching-from-SMS-Messages-resource-URI-to-Messages-resource-URI-

Comment: You're getting that when using `<Sms>` in response to a voice call? Can you perhaps start a new question and give me all the context? Thanks!

Comment: Here you go! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020962/twilio-sms-sent-using-sms-limited-to-160-characters-and-without-delivery-step