# Twilio: SMS sent using <Sms> limited to 160 characters and without Delivery Steps info

Tags: sms, twilio

I am sending an SMS with Twilio using the following TwiML code (from a bin). It is called at the end of a call, using the `action` parameter of the `<Dial>` verb.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Response>
    <Sms from="+44XXXXXXXXXX" to="{{From}}">Recording of your call with {{To}}: {{RecordingUrl}}</Sms>
</Response>
```

It works, but if the message gets too long I get the error:

> 21605 Maximum body length is 160 characters

And I do not get Delivery Steps information in the [SMS logs](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/logs/):

> Delivery Steps
>
> Delivery Steps are not available.
>
> For messages sent with the deprecated /SMS/Messages Resource. Please
>   upgrade to the Messages Resource to see Delivery Steps.

This link leads me to believe I am somehow using a deprecated API: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181028-Switching-from-SMS-Messages-resource-URI-to-Messages-resource-URI-

All the numbers involved are from UK, if this somehow has an influence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It turns out that `<Sms>` under the hood, uses the deprecated `/SMS/Messages` endpoint to send messages during calls. This is why you are seeing the results you have shared above.

There is a bug open internally to provide `<Message>` within voice calls, but in the meantime the workaround is to [use the REST API to send messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) instead of TwiML.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the research, let us know when things improve on this front!

Comment: Sorry it wasn't better news. I didn't even realise!

Comment: This still isnt fixed Twilio :( now I cant send messages because I have to update the api and the new api isnt working for twiml

Comment: Hi @James, I'm not sure what's wrong for you as this was someone else's question from a year and a half ago? Can you explain your issue and then we can work toward solving it for you? I'd recommend asking a new question on Stack Overflow or if it's more complicated than that, drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com and I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: I've the same problem, message is not allowed inside the voice response twiml API. And it still isn't a year later. I was using .sms chaining in ruby to produce twiml went to update my application and the new API didn't support it anymore and no simple way to send an SMS during a call.

Comment: That is the case right now @James, we recommend that you use the REST API to send SMS messages during a call.

Comment: Yes so you see is been almost two years for y'all at Twilio to fix it. I don't watch the application doing is own things I want it to serve the XML only

Comment: Hey @James, I've followed up internally to see what's happening with this, but right now there's not much more I can do than suggest workarounds. Can I suggest perhaps replacing your static XML with a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions) to send the message and return TwiML at the same time? That way you don't need to host a new application, but you can achieve the same result.